# Trying to return a date from android date picker

Tags: android, date, datepicker

Over the past 24 hours I have been trying to find articles about my issue but am still confused. If I have missed a place where this question was previously answered I apologize but I hope that you all will still help me understand what I am missing.

Synopsis: I want to populate a few text boxes with a date picker and am having trouble understanding how to return the selected date so that I can populate the appropriate textbox.

Basically I'm trying to implement a standard date picker targeting android devices >= 4.0.

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

You will notice that this is the code from the android documentation example that can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html 
I am implementing this code in a larger project and the date picker comes up fine, the date is picked fine etc.
What I am having trouble with is getting the date after the user selects it. Basically the user selects the date and then nothing happens. What I want to do is populate a specific text box with the date after selection. This will happen in a few text boxes so I can't just hard code it into the onDateSet function. 
My thought was to pass the textBox's id with the creation of the datepicker but I am not completely sure how I would do that.

This is my first android project and focused on comprehension and not simply getting a working project, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "onDateSet" method should be called when the user selects a date.
In this method, you can use the year, month and day passed in parameter.

Comment: The onDateSet triggers when the user selects a date. I don't know how have enough context to know which dialog box to update when that function is triggered. The issue is that my activity has multiple places to enter the date, so each time it is triggered I need to update a different textbox. I don't know how to pass the textbox to update to the function when the date has finally been picked.

Comment: Oh ok, so I think instead of implementing OnDateSetListener, you should just create a new OnDateSetListener when you create your DatePickerDialog. This way, you will have multiple "onDateSet" methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't known if that is the best way to do it, but I solve it this way:

- I have two buttons, A and B.
- When i click button A, a DatePicker appears and the user selects the date.
- After confirm the date, the text in Button A is set to that date that was selected.
- Same behavior for button B.

That is the function when button A or B is pressed:

```
public void selectDateButtons(View view){


    if(view.getId() == R.id.buttonA)
    {
            clickedButton = R.id.buttonA;
    }else{
            clickedButton = R.id.buttonB;
    }

    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");


}
```

clickedButton is a Static global variable.

Then declare the sub-class

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        if(clickedButton == R.id.ButtonA)
        {
            ButtonA.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));

        } else {
            ButtonB.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                    + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget, your main activity should extends FragmentActivity.
Hope that works for you too!
Best regards!